# How do I group together string rows with partial matching strings and then sum them together in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

| Artist | Points |
| --- | --- |
| Notorious BIG | 34 |
| Notorious BIG feat. blah blah | 42 |
| 2pac | 20 |
| 2pac feat. Dr. Dre | 30 |

I would like to group and sum by Artist for a table to look like so:

| Artist | Points |
| --- | --- |
| Notorious BIG | 76 |
| 2pac | 50 |

P.S. there are a lot of artists featuring other artists in this dataset so I cannot just do them all individually. Thanks for your help.

I was thinking maybe I should CREATE VIEW with all the feat.% removed then group the artists together? Not sure how I would go about doing that either.

```
CREATE VIEW no_feat AS
SELECT 
    REPLACE(artist, 'ft%', ' ')
FROM rankings;
```

I'm very new at this so I tried that and it obviously did not work. I dont think the replace function accepts wildcards

Comment: I recommend you to create a table which sets a relation between "free" and "canonical" artist names. Then you'd use it in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the `Artist` starting with same string need to be grouped together, the below could work:

```
Select SUBSTRING(Artist, 0,CHARINDEX(' ', Artist, 0)), SUM(Points)
From Artist
Group by SUBSTRING(Artist, 0,CHARINDEX(' ', Artist,0))
```

Comment: CHARINDEX is a MSSQL function which doesn't exist in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use substring_index for this case.

This would get all the values before `feat.`, if feat is missing entire string will returned.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(artist, 'feat.', 1) as Artist,
       sum(points) as Points
FROM my_table
GROUP BY  SUBSTRING_INDEX(artist, 'feat.', 1);
```

But, if the string contain spaces you should use TRIM as follows,

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(artist, 'feat.', 1)) as Artist,
       sum(points) as Points
FROM my_table
GROUP BY  TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(artist, 'feat.', 1));
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> Artist           Points
> Notorious BIG     76
> 2pac              50
> ```

https://dbfiddle.uk/QpaO9bVZ